# How to convert resnet50 into coreml model?

Tags: tensorflow, coreml, eager-execution

How to convert resnet50 network written in eager_execution mode into coreml?

Here is the tf resnet50 implementation:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.13/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples/resnet50/resnet50.py

Answer (score 0):

At this point, coremltools and tfcoreml don't handle eager mode. You'll need to convert your TF model to a "frozen" .pb graph file first, and then you can use tfcoreml to convert it to Core ML.

If you can't turn your model into a frozen graph file, you can't use the automated conversion tools... But even in that case, you can still create a Core ML model using NeuralNetworkBuilder (part of coremltools), but you'll have to do all of this by hand.

Comment: Thanks Matthijs!

Would you please elaborate on how I can freeze graph and save it into '.pb' format?

I have tried the solution here but it didn't work:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55529755/how-to-convert-model-in-eager-execution-to-static-graph-and-save-in-pb-file/55531285

Comment: I don't know, I haven't used TF in eager mode yet.